# Return Response before calling methods in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I do some Caching-Checks (etag) in my base controller called "CachingController"

```
public CachingController:Controller {
   public CachingController() {
      if (IsKnownEtag(Request.Headers["If-None-Match"])) {
         Response.StatusCode=304;
      }
   }
}

public MyController:CachingController {
  public ActionResult IsMagic(string dragonName) {   
     var isMagic=dragonName=="Puff";
     // ...
     SaveEtag();
     return new ActionResult(isMagic);
  }
}
```

So in the Constructor of my Base Controller I check if the Etag is valid. If it is, I want to return the status code. After I set the Status code I do not want that the Controller Action is still called. How can I do this without modifying each Action?

Comment: try Response.End(); after Response.StatusCode=304;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the etag logic to an `ActionFilterAttribute` instead:

```
public class EtagFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(IsKnownEtag(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["If-None-Match"]))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

And then use it in your controller:

```
public class MyController : CachingController
{
    [EtagFilter]
    public ActionResult IsMagic(string dragonName)
    {
        var isMagic = dragonName == "Puff";
        // ...
        SaveEtag();
        return new ActionResult(isMagic);
    }
}
```

Also, move the `SaveEtag()` method to the filter so you keep that logic away from your controller.

Comment: Sadly I cannot move the SaveETag() into the filter cause I make some validation-operations (Action 1 causes also Action 4 and 6 to revalidate etc.). Nonetheless. Your answer worked fine, thanks